# Delete one row in html table marqued by a check box with javascript

Tags: javascript

I build dynamically my HTML table from database
like that:

```
for (i = 0; i < nomCols.length; i++) {
    retour.append(("<td bgcolor=#0066CC>") + nomCols[i] + "</td>");

}
retour.append("</tr>");

retour.append("<tr>");

try {

    s = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    Query query = s.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);

    for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            Dailytimesheet object = (Dailytimesheet) it.next();
            retour.append("<td><input type=checkbox  name=cb id=cb  /> </td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getTrackingDate() + "</td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getActivity() + "</td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getProjectCode() + "</td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getWAName() + "</td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getTaskCode() + "</td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getTimeSpent() + "</td>");
            retour.append("<td>" + object.getPercentTaskComplete() + "</td>");
        }
        retour.append("</tr>");


    }

    retour.append("</table>");
    tx.commit();


} catch (HibernateException e) {
    retour.append("</table><H1>ERREUR:</H1>" + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return retour;
}
```

so I want that all check boxes having the same id.
When trying to delete one row in my table witch have the check box checked i found a problem with that.
Iam using  simple javascript like this:

```
function DeleteARow() {
    //var Rows = document.getElementById('sheet').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //var RowsCount = Rows.length;
    //alert('Your table has ' + RowsCount + ' rows.');
    if (document.getElementById('cb').checked == true) {

        document.getElementById('cb').parentNode('td').parentNode('tr').remove();

    }
}
```

It doesn't work approperly and only the first row have the id 'cb'.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `ID` is that there can be only one. You cannot have multiple elements that have the same `ID`.

`getElementByID` will only return the first element that has the ID.

I recommend you instead use CSS classes.

Here is a way you can loop through checkboxes who have `class="cb"`:

```
var j, elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (j = 0;j < elements.length;j += 1) {
    if (elements[j].className === 'cb' && elements[j].checked === true) {
        // elements[j] is your checkbox
    }
}
```

If you want to take the time to learn something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can make this entire task easier:

<strike>$('.cb:checked').parent().parent().remove();</strike>

**edit**:

```
$('.cb:checked').closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: `$('.cb:checked').closest('tr').remove();` :)

Comment: how could i declare the class="cb" and where?

Comment: I understand your proposition but when putting the style class=cb i don't have the difference.